# Best Way to Run Jenkins Master-Worker Architecture inside the AWS VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, networking, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-vpc

I am running 1-M and 2-W nodes on EC2 instances. I've created a VPC and I put the Master Node inside the Private Subnet and 2-W nodes inside the public subnet. To connect the Master node to get internet access for updates I attached the NAT Gateway. I am not sure, is this is a right approach or not? If anyone can share their approach with me, like what's the best of deploying Jenkins Master-Worker Node Architecture in the cloud or how they are company deploying this Architecture?

Comment: AWS provides info about this. [Here](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/DevOps/Jenkins_on_AWS.pdf) or [here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/setup-jenkins-build-server/services-costs/) for example. Have you checked them?

Comment: Hi Marcin, I already read that Documentation, that's really simple Case Scenario they doing. I am going to try to establish the same way I explained above. If my all connection works properly, I will share my solution with everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I like it to put it on ECS cluster and access it through ALB, Agents can be deployed on ECS too ,all will be in the private subnet with NAT gateway to reach the internet, as for the storage I am using EFS so it does auto-scale.